# React.js with Facebook censored

Tags: facebook, reactjs

If the place I am at censors Facebook (can't access the website - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED), can I still use React.js to code? React is made by Facebook and the script src needs to access a Facebook-related site to get the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can use npm to import react. All you need is the React.js script from any source.

NPM is a good way to access it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react

Also, this (importing libraries) is basic JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp